Finding the Fourier Coefficients of a repeated non-periodic signal
I need some help understanding the steps behind this exercise.

Find the Fourier coefficients of $x(t) = rep_{10}e^{-t}u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is the unit step signal.

I know the alternate way of writing the signal is $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t-kT}u(t-kT)$, but I'm unsure what to do from here. Does $u(t)$ change the bounds of the summation since it's null for all values less than zero, or does it just limit the exponential signal?
Furthermore, due to the lack of symmetry in the function, does that mean I should use the general equation for a Fourier equation $a_k =\frac{1}{T}\int_{[T]}x(t)e^{ikw_0t}dt$ or is there another approach I could take?
Any guidance is appreciated.
